# Simple jQuery selection issue

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td class="featureCell" id="featureCell_Announced">
           <div>Announced</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And I've got this jQuery:

```
$('.featureCell').each(function () {
    console.log($(this).html());   
})
```

The output I'd expect is:

```
<div>Announced</div>
```

However, the output I get is:

```
Announced
```

Why did the parent div get stripped?

Comment: Try `console.log($(this).parent().html());`

Comment: Which browser are you using and is your markup valid?

Comment: This works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/WgRae/ I wrapped the `<tr>` etc., in a `<table>`, too, btw. What browser are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the updates, but still no luck. Some additional info :-

- Using latest Chrome
- It's wrapped in a <table<tbody>...
- Alert and console.log() both give the same output (i.e. no div)

I guess I need to figure out what's different between this and the jsfiddle...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like console.log() strips the `<div>` tags or actually prints out html thus you don't see the actual `<div>` text. Try printing it out in alert or to a page and see if the `<div>` is there.

Comment: It might depend on the browser. In Chrome25 and IE9 I am seeing the expected markup (although I did have to add a `<table>` wrapper).

Answer (score 1):

`console.log` writes the output in html form , so `<div>text</div>`  but if you tried

`alert($(this).html());`  you will get the expected output

Answer (score 0):

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GFmRr/) shows that indeed `<div>Announced</div>` is outputed.

Unless you strip away the `<table>` elements, because `tr` and `td` elements are not valid elements outside of a `table`.